# How to integrate Freshdesk with SAPUI5

Tags: postman, sapui5, freshdesk

As a beginner in SAPUI5 for barcode scanning, I have already made a simple app just need to bring data.. How to integrate Freshdesk with SAPUI5 so I can bring data? I have API provided by team just need to connect so it can bring data.. I don't know how to connect.

I am stuck this point.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.